# How to split string to array with specific word in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, split

I have a string after I do a command:

```
[username@hostname ~/script]$ gsql ls | grep "Graph graph_name"
  - Graph graph_name(Vertice_1:v, Vertice_2:v, Vertice_3:v, Vertice_4:v, Edge_1:e, Edge_2:e, Edge_3:e, Edge_4:e, Edge_5:e)
```

Then I do
`IFS=", " read -r -a vertices <<< "$(gsql use graph ifgl ls | grep "Graph ifgl(" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1)"` to make the string splitted and append to array. But, what I want is to split it by delimiter ", " then append each word that contain ":v" to an array, its mean word that contain ":e" will excluded.

How to do it? without do a looping

Comment: You should also include what is the output of the `gsql` command.  Otherwise only people who are familiar with GSQL can answer, but your question is actually about shell scripting.

Comment: Yes, answers can be improved if we get this output of `gsql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Like this, using `grep`

```
mapfile -t array < <(gsql ls | grep "Graph graph_name" | grep -oP '\b\w+:v')
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `:v` | ':v' |

Comment: I would recommend the use of `mapfile` over `()` as it is more stable. Using mapfile would then be: `mapfile -t array < <(gsql ls | grep "Graph graph_name" | grep -oP '\b\w+:v')`.

Answer (score 2):

This `bash` script should work:

```bash
declare arr as array variable
arr=()

# use ", " as delimiter to parse the input fed through process substituion
while read -r -d ', ' val || [[ -n $val ]]; do
   val="${val%)}"
   val="${val#*\(}"
   [[ $val == *:v ]] && arr+=("$val")
done < <(gsql ls | grep "Graph graph_name")

# check array content
declare -p arr
```

**Output:**

```bash
declare -a arr='([0]="Vertice_1:v" [1]="Vertice_2:v" [2]="Vertice_3:v" [3]="Vertice_4:v")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a condition per element the logical way is to use a loop. There may be ways to do it, but here is a solution with a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="Vertice_1:v, Vertice_2:v, Vertice_3:v, Vertice_4:v, Edge_1:e, Edge_2:e, Edge_3:e, Edge_4:e, Edge_5:e"
input="${input//,/ }" #replace , with SPACE (bash array uses space as separator)
inputarray=($input)
outputarray=()
for item in "${inputarray[@]}"; do
  if [[ $item =~ ":v" ]]; then
    outputarray+=($item) #append the item to the output array
  fi
done
echo "${outputarray[@]}"
```

will give output: `Vertice_1:v Vertice_2:v Vertice_3:v Vertice_4:v`

since the elements don't have space in them this works